# How to mock the following method via Mockito in junit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

In my service class i have this

```
CacheLookupPolling_Darwin CacheLookupPolling_Darwin_FRAGMENT = beanFactory.getBean(CacheLookupPolling_Darwin.class);
String s = CacheLookupPolling_Darwin_FRAGMENT.cacheLookupPolling_Darwin(String, httpHeaders);
```

the class CacheLookupPolling_Darwin defines a DefaultHttpServletRequest like this

```
private DefaultHttpServletRequest Request;
```

In this class the function cacheLookupPolling_Darwin performs the following initialization:

```
Request = (DefaultHttpServletRequest) ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

how can i mock this Request behaviour in my test class, the .getRequest() throws a nullPointerException.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the `CacheLookupPolling_Darwin` bean in your test class using `@MockBean` and then mock it's behavior with Mockito.

For example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTestSuite {


    @MockBean
    private CacheLookupPolling_Darwin cacheLookupPolling_Darwin;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        given(cacheLookupPolling_Darwin.cacheLookupPolling_Darwin(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any()))
                .willReturn("mocked return value"));
    }

}
```